# ActiveResource: specify retry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeresource

I'm using ActiveResource for long-running import and synchronization jobs. Is there a way to specify retries for failed requests? I want to avoid ugly begin/rescue/retry constructs around each and every ActiveResource request.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on logical/ coding failure. If coding failure is going to be there then you need to catch exception using rescue only ;)

If logical failure then you can just push to failure stack and reprocess the same afterwards.

Comment: With "failure", I mean HTTP timeouts mainly. What is your advice how to deal with that?

Comment: @OrtwinGentz I think you should override the https request method such a way that in case failure it should retry for 2-3 times and thereafter give up and log the full trace of exception and continue execution further.